# Child only breaks out of inline-grid parent in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-grid

I want the image centered within my button but it breaks out in Firefox while it works flawlessly in Google Chrome. Why does this occur and how can I prevent it from happening?

Here is the code:

```css
button {
    all: unset;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: firebrick;
}

button img {
    height: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Black_square.jpg"></button>
```

Here is what it looks in **Chrome**:

[image: Chrome]

And in **Firefox**:

[image: Firefox]

Comment: TL;DR: don't use a button as a flex or grid container

Comment: Instead of width: 50px you have to specify grid-template-columns: 50px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display: inline-grid is not needed. Button is a block element and everything set in the body will be in the middle of the button

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

button img {
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Black_square.jpg"></button>
```

Comment: *Button is a block element and everything set in the body will be in the middle of the button* : can you explain what you mean by this? button isn't a block element

Comment: @TemaniAfif true. The `Button` element is by default an `inline-block` element.
Nevertheless the core of the answer is correct. Removing `inline-grid` will solve the problem.

Comment: It is however not 100% centered, is it? It looks shifted upwards

Comment: @j.Doe removing everything will also work (margin:auto, text-align:center) .. but still don't understand the explanation

Comment: I wrote it wrong, I meant that every element of text or in this case img placed between the opening and closing the tag will be inside this button.

Comment: @MiXT4PE you need `display:block` to the image to avoid the whitespace at the bottom and it will be centred